# Change Individual Keys on a Second Keyboard Only

Tags: java, i3-window-manager, xkb

Without using xkbcomp. An alternative to xkb, because I can't get xkbcomp to work with java applications. Any suggestions? I'm stumped.

Trying to get xkbcomp to work with java applications. Terminal output
https://pastebin.com/M0jud0Sq

Fedora + i3

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. First, please to not place the question only in the title: This makes the body of your post unclear. Second, please add any additional details you can regarding how things are currently, how you would like them to be once this is solved, any research you have done and any steps you have tried and their outcome.

Comment: Hey music2myear, thanks for the warming welcoming and thanks for sharing some helpful tips. I edited my thread without addressing you. I posted again with your suggestions. I appreciate your time.